# Save Gridview data as Template

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a report generated in Gridview and I want to save the report as a template for later retrieval. I do not want to export to excel. The template should available for user to retrieve and see whenever he logs in. I am using VS 2008 and C#/ASP.NET

I do format the gridview data source according to some business logic and presentation purposes before binding it to the gridview so I can not just keep the retrieval SQL in the database.

Any idea?

Comment: The best place would be the [dbms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_management_system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just save the retrieval data filter control's values to database as a template and later it will be available for user to select and generate report.

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to create a 'snapshot' of the data, that is, data that will be served up for historical purposes and will never change, I recommend creating your export (whether it's excel, word, pdf, etc), and save the file either to the file system or the database.

Another option would be to create a set of 'snapshot' tables which are essentially identical to your 'live' tables and you would query from those tables using your original sql statement.  You might include some UI allowing the user to filter this data based on some date range.